# Copy ONLY recent by DateLastModified file over VbScript

Tags: file, vbscript, copy, last-modified

New at VbScript so please include all lines if you can.
I have 
Source-folder C:\s\ with files with names et_v01.txt, et_v02.txt etc.    Destination-folder C:\d\ I only want the latest file to be COPIED from S to D which would be et_v02 since we'll use DateLastModified.

Bonus at destination only keep the latest file if it runs next time      when a new version comes in.    Thanks in advance and I have searched    for this but the others had    less than criteria and etc.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objSTR, objEND, objTYP, objEXT, objKEY, objFILE
Dim Folder, SubFolder

objSTR = "C:\s\"
objEND = "C:\d\"

For Each objFILE in objFSO.GetFolder(objSTR).Files
 If objFILE.DateLastModified > DateAdd("d",-4,now) then
     objFILE.Copy objEND
 End If
Next
```

Comment: No, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.  Please show what you have tried, and we may be able to help you with a *specific* issue.  Otherwise, this question will be closed.

Comment: Put code in your question please, not in a comment.

Comment: I went ahead and did an edit in the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this version:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim strSource, strDestination

strSource = "C:\s\"
strDestination = "C:\d\"
Dim objFile, objOldestFileSoFar

For Each objFile in objFSO.GetFolder(strSource).Files
    If Not IsEmpty(objOldestFileSoFar) Then
        If objFile.DateLastModified > objOldestFileSoFar.DateLastModified Then
            Set objOldestFileSoFar = objFile
        End If
    Else 'This is the first loop, i.e. we have no previous "last mod" to compare against.
        Set objOldestFileSoFar = objFile
    End If
Next

objOldestFileSoFar.Copy strDestination
```

Also, I've cleaned up your code a bit to get rid of unused declarations and to apply better naming to your variables.  Take those as suggestions if you like, but just keep in mind that adhering to conventions is important.